# Problems in installing Jedis (when executing jar file)

Tags: java, redis, manifest, jedis

I am trying to install Java redis client (Jedis). After downloading some of its packages (for example jedis-2.1.0.jar) from [jedis download page](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/downloads) and trying to execute it with command:

> java -jar jedis-2.1.0.jar

I got this type of message:

> no main manifest attribute, in jedis-2.1.0.jar

I also read [wiki jedis page](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started) but I don't understand how to use "Getting started" from that page for installation.

Comment: Same question. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Java client for redis, you can add the jar to your project and then [download redis](http://redis.io/download) 
and install redis, not jedis